# HAXM device is not found

Tags: android-studio, haxm

How to solve this issue ?
I have already followed according to youtube and google.
But it doesn't work in my computer at all.
Please help me. Please check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lLf.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download haxm installer from :
https://www.filecroco.com/download-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

and restarting android studio solved my problem.
I hope this way works for you.